# Is it possible to connect to Node.js's net moudle from browser?

Tags: node.js, websocket, tcp, socket.io, tcpclient

i want to make TCP server with Node.js and then connect it from browser without http , express and socket.io moudles. something like what i do in java or c# but this time from browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser does not contain the capability for Javascript in a regular web page to make a straight TCP socket connection to some server.

Browser Javascript has access to the following network connection features:

1. Make an http/https request to an external server.
2. Make a webSocket connection to an external server.
3. Use webRTC to communicate with other computers

In all these cases, you must use the libraries built into the browser in order to initiate connections on these specific protocols.

There is no capability built into the browser for a plain TCP socket connection.  A webSocket (which can only connect to a webSocket server) is probably the closest you can come.

Comment: can i connect with web socket to tcp server?

Comment: @EsmailJamshidiasl - No.  As my answer says, a webSocket client can only connect to a webSocket server.  It's a whole connection scheme (with security built-in) and data format protocol.

Comment: i found https://github.com/websockets/ws. I NEED THIS. thank you. and is http request fast like tcp or websocket?

Comment: @EsmailJamshidiasl - If your communication is from client to server (client sending something to the server or client requesting something from the server), then http is pretty well optimized for that and will generally be your simplest option.  The `fetch()` interface in browsers is built for that. If you want a full two-way communication path where the server can send the client data at any time, then you will want a lasting webSocket connection.  But, there is a server-side cost to having a continuous webSocket connection with every active client.

Comment: @EsmailJamshidiasl - FYI, here's a nice primer on networking from Javascript in a browser: https://hpbn.co/primer-on-browser-networking/.